# Give an example of a relation S on the set A={a,b,c,d} such that S is transitive, anti symmetric, and irreflexive.

Tags: logic

I know the answer is (a,b), but I do not see how this is transitive.
Also, can someone please explain antisymmetric to me. I only know how to see if it is antisymmetric when drawing a digraph.

Comment: The empty relation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation

Answer (score 1):

A nice, intuitive example of such a relation is the "strictly less than" relation on the integers:

Transitive: if $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$

Anti-symmetric: if $a < b$ then $b \nless a$

Irreflexive: $a \nless a$

Anti-symmetric means that, for a relation $R$, $R(a,b)$ and $R(b,a)$ cannot both be true unless $a=b$.  Basically you can't swap the two elements in the relation.

Comment: Thanks, but how is (a,b) transitive, there is no "c" such that it fits your transitive definition?

Comment: @A.B "c" needs not fit anything. If there are no $c$ for which $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ then the relation is transitive, vacuously. The empty relation also works, as pointed in a comment (and in that case there is no even $a,b$).

Answer (score 1):

$R=\{(a,b)\}$ is antisymmetric, since $(b,a)\notin R$. (Also, since 
none of $(a,c),(c,a),(a,d)$ etc, is in $R$.)

It is transitive, vacuously, since there are no $x,y,z$ with 
$(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R)$ (so then you need not worry 
about $(x,z)$ at all). Indeed, if say $(x,y)\in R$ then 
$(x,y)$ must be $(a,b)$, but then use that $(b,z)\notin R$ regardless of $z$.

$R=\{(a,b)\}$ is an answer, but it is not "the" answer. Clearly, $R=\{(a,c)\}$ is just as good an answer. As pointed in a comment $R=\emptyset$ is an answer.

Comment: @A.B happy to hear that, you may also accept and/or vote up an answer if you like it http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer